# How do I scroll images which are placed like a cards closed to each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scroll, playing-cards

I have image view with cards (images) placed in it i would like to scroll those cards in right and left direction. Cards are overlapping so how should i scroll them.

Answer (score 0):

Hey dude are you looking for something like this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Have a look at 100 ways to motivate others application in that see cards in landscape orientation.